# FireMonkey Location Sensor does not turn off

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, android-sensors, delphi-xe5

I'm using Delphi XE5 (no any update)

My application running smoothly (CPU %1-%5) (Device:Samsung Note 2, Android:4.4.2)

When Location Sensor Active=true (CPU %25-%50) and I'm read latitude and longitude values then set Location Sensor Active=false but CPU does not fall, only %25-%50

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you but the sensor.active = true? Maybe it keeps on getting called so it puts it back on. Can you post you code?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this too. It appears that the location service (GPS receiver) is not controlled by TLocationSensor.Active, but your app's access to the sensor is. Having stepped through code with the debugger in CBXE6, it seems that the receiver is still running and the CPU is processing data even when your app has stopped using the receiver. That makes sense since GPS it is a system-wide service.